# Gradle: why conventional java build classes path is reversed to java source path

Tags: java, gradle, build, conventions

I am curious what is the good reason for the inversion:

project/src/**main/java**/pckgLev0/pckgLev1/...

project/build/classes/**java/main**/pckgLev0/pckgLev1/...

Answer (score 2):

This changed with Gradle 4.x.

From the [gradle discussions](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/build-path-for-java-classes-changed-from-3-x-to-4-x/24168):

> The reason we went with build/classes/java/main vs build/classes/main/java is that it was less likely to break in strange ways with builds and plugins that hardcoded the path to build/classes/main or snuck outputs into build/classes/main.